# How can I exclude a page from .htaccess rules?

Tags: .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|jscript|user_guide|login|en|favicon.ico|uploads|script.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And I want to be able to type this adress directly:

```
mysite.com/system/application/views/req-php.php?_INPUT&f=xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another negative `RewriteCond` to avoid rewriting for this new URL:

```
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/system/application/views/req-php\.php\?_INPUT&f= [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|jscript|user_guide|login|en|favicon.ico|uploads|script.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: ok it is updated now. Tell me exact URL do you see in browser and make sure this is the first rule below `RewriteEngine On` line.